# IIS ARR return 404

Tags: iis, arr

I am doing some experiments with k8s cluster which I have on my own private server. but I have some issues.

First of all my infrastructure:

I have public static IP, and wildcard domain in DNS (i.e. *.k8s.myperttydomain.com bound to X.X.X.X). I can PING this domain from internet.

I have gateway listening on ports 80 and 443 port on X.X.X.X and forward requests to LAN to SERVER-1. SERVER-1 is WIN2016 server with IIS .

Using IIS  I have some application that  work without any problems.I can reach it from internet or LAN (I have DNS on LAN with internal addresses of service).

For example, we have server service.myprettydomain.com with has DNS recrod in public DNS to X.X.X.X and in private DNS to SERVER-1

Now we add k8s cluster and want to forward all request for host *.k8s.myprettydomain.com to it

I have  enabled ARR in IIS, enable proxy (setup address as 127.0.0.1), enable URL rewrite to inspect incoming requests, turn of ssl offloading and add to URL rewrite following rule: 
pattern: * (wildcard)
condition: {HTTP_HOST} match *.k8s.myprettydomain.com
action: rewrite http://{R:0}

When I try to access it from internet I get 404 error.
I can't find any log for request - not in events, not in failed requests, so I don't know where start to search for the problem.

I tried to specify rewrite target to some service on SERVER-1, but get same result so I think that I misunderstand how ARR should work.

Suggestions how to solve this task

**UPDATE 1** ok, may be i try to invent a bicycle, and there is another, more simple way, but... there is scheme and some additional comments:
[scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yO98.png)

so, what i want. i want to have service in k8s host, which can obtain ssl certificate from lets encrypt and i can access this service both form WWW and LAN.

Comment: Hello. Sorry, I can't understand what goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you give us a look to your configuration?